# How to remove combustion door for Kenmore Power Miser 9 water heater?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I removed the two screws on the sides of the door and tubes coming out from controller. However, the combustion door still don't want to come off so that I could service thermocouple (I have seen how this is done for other water heaters and access was easy in those cases). There are no other obvious screws that I see on the doors.

[image]

I found [this](http://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/665579/kenmore-power-miser-15333926-power-miser-153339410-ha-power-miser-153339511-ha-power-miser-15333946-power-miser-15333936-power-miser-153339210-ha.html?page=30&original=1) "PARTS ORDER LIST" (although mine water heater Model # is 153.330952).

[image]

It shows parts, but it really does not explicitly point what else could be preventing the doors from coming off.

1. Could it be that door gasket due to temperature is simply stuck and I need to apply some force to remove the doors (or pry with screw driver)?
2. Is the gasket [factory] glued by any chance?
3. Any other ideas how to get to thermocouple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The door gasket was the one preventing doors from coming off. After prying carefully prying doors from all sides with screwdriver the doors came off.